# How does this branch-less while loop work

Tags: c++, facebook, compression

I read about Facebook's recent new [ZStandard compression yesterday](https://www.infoq.com/news/2016/09/facebook-zstandard-compression) and part of it explained that it was faster thanks, in part, to branchless while loops.

Can anyone explain how it works?

```
/* classic version */
while (nbBitsUsed >= 8) { /* each while test is a branch */
  accumulator <<= 8;
  accumulator += *byte++;
  nbBitsUsed  -= 8;
}

/* branch-less version */
nbBytesUsed = nbBitsUsed >> 3;
nbBitsUsed &= 7;
ptr += nbBytesUsed;
accumulator = read64(ptr);
```

Comment: It's missing parts. That's not the same code at all. First reads bytes depending on the value, the other seems to skip based on the value.

Comment: The code is clearly silly, since `nbBitsUsed &= 7;` changes the value of `nbBitsUsed`, but the resulting value is not used for anything.

Comment: The fragment is too short, but the general point is to read an (unaligned) qword instead of filling the buffer byte by byte.